# unique_ptr & vector, trying to access deleted function, Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, unique-ptr, oglplus

I am trying to use unique_ptr to manage my memory, and VS2013 seems to be giving me trouble when I think it shouldn't be.

It would seem that the compiler is for whatever reason trying to access a deleted copy constructor when it really should have no reason to do so.

This is what one of my classes looks like:

```
class Mesh
{
public:
    Mesh(oglplus::Program* program, const std::vector<Vertex>& vertices, 
                    const std::vector<GLuint>& indices);
    void draw();
private:
    const oglplus::Program* _program;
    std::vector<Vertex> _vertices;
    std::vector<GLuint> _indices;
    oglplus::Buffer _faceBuffer;
    oglplus::Buffer _vertexBuffer;
    oglplus::VertexArray _vao;
};

class Model
{
public:
    Model(std::string filename, oglplus::Program* program);
    void draw();
private:
    const oglplus::Program* _program;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Mesh>> _meshes;
};
```

The issue is with the line

```
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Mesh>> _meshes;
```

it starts spewing things like

```
2>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(593): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Model::Mesh,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty=Model::Mesh
2>          ]
2>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory(1486) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<Model::Mesh,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr'
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty=Model::Mesh
2>          ]
2>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(592) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)'
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Model::Mesh,std::default_delete<Model::Mesh>>
2>          ]
2>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Model::Mesh,std::default_delete<Model::Mesh>>
2>          ]
2>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\type_traits(572) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Model::Mesh,std::default_delete<Model::Mesh>>
2>          ]
2>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector(650) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_empty<_Alloc>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Model::Mesh,std::default_delete<Model::Mesh>>>
2>          ]
2>          c:\users\vitali\projects\3d-stg\source\model\model.hpp(45) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Model::Mesh,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty=Model::Mesh
2>          ]
2>  model.cpp
```

I am not using `std::vector::resize()` or anything like that (in-fact I commented out all uses of my _meshes vector, and even tried commenting the implementation out completely to no avail), so I don't understand why the compiler is giving me issues.

Does anybody have any ideas?

---

Thank you Preetish Kakkar for finding the issue. It turns out it was an issue with compiler generated functions implicitly using the copy constructor and operator= of the Mesh class forcing the compiler to try and use deleted functions.

Comment: Try implementing a move constructor for `Mesh`. AFAIK, VS2013 does not auto-generate move constructors / move assignment operators.

Comment: Right, but it is my understanding that std::vector doesn't use move constructors, and thus no errors should be present. If I am reading the error correctly it has something to do with copy constructors. Also if instead of std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Mesh>> _meshes;  I do  std::unique_ptr<Mesh> _mesh, everything compiles fine. Also if I just use regular pointer std::vector<Mesh*> _meshes, everything compiles fine also.

Comment: Are you using `-std=c++11` mode?

Comment: Are you trying to copy an object of your `Model` class? Also, the code you provided and the error messages don't align: the error seems to indicate that `Mesh` is a member of `Model` which is not the case with the code you posted.

Comment: -std=c++11 does not apply to VS afaik

Comment: @dietmar-kuhl All of those are in classes are in a Model namespace, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: This is a known bug in VS 2013. It is classified as an active bug by Microsoft. See below: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/858243/c-cli-compiler-error-trying-to-std-move-a-std-unique-ptr-to-parameter-taken-by-value

Comment: That bug is C++/CLI only.

Comment: It isn't C++/CLI only in VS2013 (update 5). It happens to me in C++/Native

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I reproduced your problem, below is sample code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Mesh
{
public: 
    Mesh() {}
    void draw() {}
private:
};

class Model
{
public:
    Model() {}
    void draw() {}
private:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Mesh> MeshUniquePtr;
    std::vector<MeshUniquePtr> _meshes;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Model m;
    Model m1;
    m = m1; // causes error as you can't copy unique ptr

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is at some point you are trying to copy two model object which can't be done as unique_ptr is not copyable.

Comment: Can you paste the code of file which is giving error when compiling it. This error can only occur in case if you are trying to copy the unique_ptr (at least from what you posted it looks so). I am certain that it is happening.

Comment: So I found the problem in your code, Ship.hpp is where the problem is coming from. It is using Model::model which is fine but is causing problem because it's trying to copy. Making copy constructor and assignment operator private in Model.hpp will fix it. add                                                             Model(Model const&);
void operator=(Model const&); in model class private section

Comment: Or you can fix it by removing default from Ship(const Ship&) = default; If you want to just not have ship be copyable then just make assignment & copy constructor private - Don't provide them default implementation as default will try to copy internally causing error.

Comment: I have other suggestion for not including everything inside typedefs.hpp - include whatever is required in each cpp

Comment: Why do you think including everything in typedefs.hpp is bad? Sure it can slow down the compile time, but if in the future I decide to use precompiled headers this easy afaik. My issue with including everything I need, is that it is really hard to keep track of what I really need, and I end up having a lot of "useless" headers dirtying my code.

Comment: As you could see your original problem was coming from ship.hpp & not model.hpp/cpp but as you had everything included a lot of stuff was getting included (ship.hpp including it's default copy const with impl) which was also getting compiled when you were trying to compile model.cpp (making debugging of problem harder). There is no need for model.cpp to include ship.hpp. You can use pch but then what you find is common is what should be in common.hpp or something similar instead of everything. There are lot of other reasons you can find by googling or looking at stack overflow.